# Existence of a curve with no points over finite separable field extensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, rational-points

Does there exist a field $K$, and a smooth projective geometrically connected curve $C$ over $K$ such that, for all finite separable field extensions $L/K$ the curve $C$ has no $L$-rational points?

I am interested in the case where $K$ is a function field of transcendence degree one over  1) a finite field or 2) an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: I believe the answer should be *no*, since separably closed fields are pseudo algebraically closed.

Comment: Ow of course, any geometrically reduced algebraic variety over a field $k$ has a point over the separable closure $k^s$ of $k$.